# Fix window tab to hold window in the frame?

Tags: windows

Both of the actual tabs on the window have broken off, so when opening or closing the window it tends to want to come out of the frame. No matter what I Google, the only results I get have to do with replacing tabs on window *screens*, which isn't my problem.

Is it possible to replace these tabs? Or do I need to buy a whole new window?

**This is the broken tab:**

[image]

**This is a functional tab:**

[image]

Comment: Would try window "stops", instead of tabs.  Would like to think just the stops are replaceable, but you will need to know the window maker to search for replacements.  Not enough picture to tell how they are mounted, might need the whole section.  In the time can usually use small wood pieces to hold the window up.

Comment: Your photo one shows window been out of alignment ? It looks like it is missing a seal.